# ASP.NET MVC - Assign variable to input hidden field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, variables, input, hidden, assign

I would like to try to assign a variable value to input hidden field in my MVC form. I thought I could do it this way but the values of variables are not being put to the hidden fields.
Any thoughts why this is a wrong way?

note: there is some code in between the variables declaration ... I just wanted to make things simple to read. The particular line of code that bugs me is: @value = @secondNumber

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Jakub Holovsky - Contact";

    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    int firstNumber = randomNumber.Next(0, 11);
    int secondNumber = randomNumber.Next(0, 11);
    int sumNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
}

<div class="divLeftSide">
                        <span>How much is @firstNumber + @secondNumber:</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstNumber, new { @type = "number", @id = "firstNumber", @class = "HiddenField", @value = @firstNumber })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecondNumber, new { @type = "number", @id = "secondNumber", @class = "HiddenField", @value = @secondNumber })
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a class named SomeModel for your model. The class should contain the properties named FirstNumber and SecondNumber.

2) Add the line

```
@model SomeModel
```

to your view.

3) Move

```
Random randomNumber = new Random();
int firstNumber = randomNumber.Next(0, 11);
int secondNumber = randomNumber.Next(0, 11);
int sumNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
```

into your controller's action.

4) In your controller's action, initialize a new instance of SomeModel named model and set the FirstNumber to firstNumber and SecondNumber to secondNumber

5) Pass the model to your view by calling return View(model);

6) Remove the @value = @firstNumber and @value = @secondNumber from your view.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer it kinda helped me to understand more the whole thing. But the idea is to generate random numbers on controller which you showed me and then pass that to view. The user will fill in the result of sum of these two numbers and pass them back to my controller. How do I keep these numbers saved somewhere I mean the two? How can I persist their values through this? THank you

Comment: You could do what you are doing now, i.e. by using @@Html.TextBoxFor, or you can use @@Html.HiddenFor, which is hidden by default. Then in your controller, add the method [HttpPost]public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model), and the parameter model will get the FirstNumber and SecondNumber from those @@Html.HiddenFor that's in the view. You might also want to add one more property TheirSum to SomeModel so as to display the textbox @@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.TheirSum) and retrieve its value in the controller.

Comment: Thank you! That has helped me. One more thing, what is the most recommended way to keep state in MVC. Is it sessions?

Comment: I disabled SessionState in order for my application to pass the IBM Rational AppScan session fixation scan. So I keep states using Html.HiddenFor if it can't be recreated, and recreate states from the DB otherwise. I store User ID, Username and User's Name in the Authentication cookie just for convenience.